# create linked list with for loop...why we should use l->next.....why we can just use l=t only to assigne the previous address of the node?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;
struct node
{
    int data;
    node* next;
};

void Display(node* p)
{
while (p != NULL)
{
    printf("%d ", p->data);
    p = p->next;
}
}
int main()
{
    node* t = new node{ 0 }, * head = t;
    node* l = t;
    for (size_t i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        t = new node;
        t->data = i;
        t->next = NULL;
        l->next = t;
        l = t;

}
    Display(head);
    return 0;
}
```

why we should use l->next=t ......is this a right way to fill a linked list throw a for loop or even copy items from an array or any source of data;

Comment: Without `l->next=t`, how do you expect nodes to know what comes next?

Comment: You could also do something like `t->next = new node { i }; t = t->next;`.

Answer (score 1):

If you will write

```
l = t;
```

instead of

```
l->next = t;
l = t;
```

then the list will be broken because the data member `next` of the node pointed to by the pointer `l` will not point to the new node pointed to by the pointer `t` and will have the value `NULL`.

As a result you will have six separate nodes the data member `next` of which will be equal to `NULL`. **So you will not have a linked list**.

Comment: @aslamlouati See my answer.